# Firebase authentication with Cypress

Tags: firebase, authentication, testing, cypress, web-api-testing

I'm having issues with creating a custom command in Cypress that will allow my user to log in programatically rather than through the UI. I have pulled a lot of this from a tutorial and perhaps it is slightly outdated.

My custom command is as follows(leaving out credentials for obvious reasons):

commands.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
//import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Cypress.Commands.add("login", (email='******', password='*****') =>{
    //Log in without needing the UI
    return firebase.default.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
})
```

I am getting an error when I try to run that command as above. I have checked Firebase docs and they seem to recommend using 'import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"' and 'const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)' which I have commented out, as I am not sure how to use this in the return statement with the signInWithEmailAndPassword function.

Would really appreciate anyones help here. Thank you! :)